# How do I compile a C++ dll to work with Lua? (I'm getting Error loading module)

Tags: c++, dll, lua

When I type require ("C:/Path/To/Dll/mylib.dll") during an interactive Lua session I get this error

```
error loading module 'C:\...\mylib.dll' from file 'C:\Program Files\Lua\5.3.4\clib\libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll'
%1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

When I do:

```
f = package.loadlib("C:/Path/To/Dll/mylib.dll")
f()
```

Lua crashes, and if I run the debugger, I can see it crashes here:

```
l_noret luaG_errormsg (lua_State *L) {
    if (L->errfunc != 0) {
        StkId errfunc = restorestack(L, L->errfunc);
        if (!ttisfunction(errfunc)) luaD_throw(L, LUA_ERRERR);//<<< HERE
        setobjs2s(L, L->top, L->top - 1);
        setobjs2s(L, L->top - 1, errfunc);
        L->top++;
        luaD_call(L, L->top - 2, 1, 0);
    }
    luaD_throw(L, LUA_ERRRUN);
}
```

The error originates from here:

```
LUALIB_API void luaL_checkversion_ (lua_State *L, lua_Number ver) {
    const lua_Number *v = lua_version(L);
    if (v != lua_version(NULL))
        luaL_error(L, "multiple Lua VMs detected");//<<< HERE
    else if (*v != ver)
        luaL_error(L, "version mismatch: app. needs %f, Lua core provides %f", ver, *v);
    /* check conversions number -> integer types */
    lua_pushnumber(L, -(lua_Number)0x1234);
    if (lua_tointeger(L, -1) != -0x1234 ||
        lua_tounsigned(L, -1) != (lua_Unsigned)-0x1234)
        luaL_error(L, "bad conversion number->int;"
              " must recompile Lua with proper settings");
    lua_pop(L, 1);
```

}

I might have done something wrong while installing the binaries. These values are in my PATH:

```
C:\Program Files\Lua\5.3.4\
C:\Program Files\Lua\5.3.4\clibs
```

I also have these environment variables:

```
LUA_CPATH: C:\Program Files\Lua\5.3.4\clib\libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll
LUA_DEV: C:\Program Files\Lua\5.3.4\src
LUA_PATH: C:\Program Files\Lua\5.3.4\?.luac
```

To compile my code, I included Lua's source code in my solution (I don't think this is how it's done, so this is probably another issue).

Here's my header file:

```
#pragma once
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
    #include "lua.h"
    #include "lualib.h"
    #include "lauxlib.h"

    int l_cond ( lua_State * L );
    int l_bor ( lua_State * L );
    int l_band ( lua_State * L );
    int l_bxor ( lua_State * L );
    int l_bnot ( lua_State * L );
    int l_lshift ( lua_State * L );
    int l_rshift ( lua_State * L );
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#ifndef WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#endif

#include <SDKDDKVer.h>
#include <windows.h>
```

Here's my C++ code:

```
#include "mylib.h"

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

static const luaL_Reg lib[] = {
    { "cond", l_cond },
    { "bor", l_bor },
    { "band", l_band },
    { "bxor", l_bxor },
    { "bnot", l_bnot },
    { "lshift", l_lshift },
    { "rshift", l_rshift },
    {NULL, NULL}
};


__declspec( dllexport ) int luaopen_mylib ( lua_State *L )
{
    luaL_newlib ( L, lib );
}

static int l_cond ( lua_State *L )
{
    /*if ( lua_gettop ( L ) < 3 )
    {
        return luaL_error ( L, "l_cond expecting 3 arguments" );
    }*/

    lua_toboolean ( L, 1 ) ? lua_pushvalue ( L, 2 ) : lua_pushvalue ( L, 3 );
    return 1;
}

static int l_bor ( lua_State *L )
{
    /*if ( lua_gettop ( L ) < 2 )
    {
        return luaL_error ( L, "l_bor expecting 2 arguments" );
    }*/

    lua_Integer a = lua_tointeger ( L, 1 );
    lua_Integer b = lua_tointeger ( L, 2 );

    lua_pushinteger ( L, a | b );
    return 1;
}

static int l_band ( lua_State *L )
{
    /*if ( lua_gettop ( L ) < 2 )
    {
        return luaL_error ( L, "l_band expecting 2 arguments" );
    }*/

    lua_Integer a = lua_tointeger ( L, 1 );
    lua_Integer b = lua_tointeger ( L, 2 );

    lua_pushinteger ( L, a & b );
    return 1;
}

static int l_bxor ( lua_State *L )
{
    /*if ( lua_gettop ( L ) < 2 )
    {
        return luaL_error ( L, "l_bxor expecting 2 arguments" );
    }*/

    lua_Integer a = lua_tointeger ( L, 1 );
    lua_Integer b = lua_tointeger ( L, 2 );

    lua_pushinteger ( L, a ^ b );
    return 1;
}

static int l_bnot ( lua_State *L )
{
    /*if ( lua_gettop ( L ) < 1 )
    {
        return luaL_error ( L, "l_bxor expecting 1 argument" );
    }*/

    lua_Integer a = lua_tointeger ( L, 1 );

    lua_pushinteger ( L, ~a );
    return 1;
}

static int l_lshift ( lua_State *L )
{
    /*if ( lua_gettop ( L ) < 2 )
    {
        return luaL_error ( L, "l_lshift expecting 2 arguments" );
    }*/

    lua_Integer value = lua_tointeger ( L, 1 );
    lua_Integer shift = lua_tointeger ( L, 2 );

    lua_pushinteger ( L, value << shift );
    return 1;
}

static int l_rshift ( lua_State *L )
{
    /*if ( lua_gettop ( L ) < 2 )
    {
        return luaL_error ( L, "l_rshift expecting 2 arguments" );
    }*/

    lua_Integer value = lua_tointeger ( L, 1 );
    lua_Integer shift = lua_tointeger ( L, 2 );

    lua_pushinteger ( L, value >> shift );
    return 1;
}
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

besides those two files, as mentioned above, I also included the entirety of Lua's source code in my project. It all compiles, but I get that error when trying to load. This is all very new to me, I'm aware there's probably more than just one thing wrong with my attempt.

Comment: Someone removed the C tag for some reason, even though the entirety of the code is written in C...

Comment: "Someone" is clearly shown in the edit history. If you want to ask something, address the person directly, not a snarky note. The reason I removed the C tag is beecause you clearly ask about a C**++** dll and state it is C++. C++ is not C and `extern "C"` does not make your code C code! Maybe you first make up your mind which language you use before asking and don't spam tags.

Comment: I merely accepted the tags suggested by Stack Overflow engine. The code is C-standard compliant, I think.

Comment: Identical syntax does not imply identical semantics. And there are no "suggestions", only matches. Of yurse if you type "c", there will show up all other tags starting with "c". That does not mean you shall add tags for different languages. So, if you compile as C++ (which your text suggets), it is **not** C. They are clearly distinct languages. Whoever told you different does not know at least one of them well enough to write more than a "Hello World"! Apart from that, `__declspec` is neither standard C nor standard C++.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't include Lua source code into your project.
You should link with Lua DLL.

Update:

The simplest way to link with Lua DLL, just include this line (fix path and library name of course):

```
#pragma comment(lib, "C:\\path\\to\\Lua5.X.lib")
```

Comment: I highly suspected that. How do I do that? I'm terrible with the Linker. I'm more of a C# person. I'm ever writing a new question.